# No file type associations for KDE 5 desktop on a Debian installation

Tags: debian, kde, kde5

Running Debian Unstable with KDE 5, when I click on any type of file, there's no association with any applications and the dialogue to associate pops up everytime. Even associating some file with applications, it doesn't stuck. `update-desktop-database` doesn't do anything (even after rebooting) and there are several files on /usr/share/applications, including `mimeinfo.cache`, with the associations there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kde5 on Debian is available partially. Be aware that some apps are from Kde4 and some from Kde5. I think everyone experience problems now, but they are different, so it's hard to tell what you need to do.

All we can do now is to wait.... or try LxQt http://lxqt.org/ . It looks it uses Qt5, is more resource friendly and less problematic.

If you want to install from packages you can add theese lines to /etc/apt/sources

```
# lxqt
deb     http://packages.siduction.org/lxqt  unstable  main
deb-src http://packages.siduction.org/lxqt  unstable  main
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the status of KDE 5 on Debian Sid and probably my problem is caused by the transition, but your response does not answer my question. Especially when recommends mix Debian with Sidux.

Comment: From what I understand about Sidux it is a version of Debian unstable with a more selective approach to packaging. Is there a major difference between it and Debian unstable?